# Output to stdout and external txt file

Tags: linux, bash, unix, redirection

I am trying to redirect the stdout of a particular output to a txt file, however I would still like to view it in the console log

```bash
tail -f /var/log/kern.log | ./prsfwlog -f elfs/prs_log.elf | \
grep -E --line-buffered "RSSI|SNR" | sed -n -e 's/^.*RTS\/Grant //p'
```

this is the line that gets me the desired output
I have tried a variety of redirects and tees and have not been successful

Comment: How are you using `tee` ?

Comment: Using `tee` is the logical answer. Perhaps you could show us what you did that didn't work.

Comment: as mentioned, `tee` is the proper answer but you can indeed use `tail` but you will need to `tail` the command from either a different terminal or turn that one loose with `&` and tail from there..

Comment: tee >( grep -E "RSSI|SNR" ) RSSI_SNR_LOGS.txt
I added this to the end of my code with a |

Answer (score 0):

Try

```sh
tail -f /var/log/kern.log | ./prsfwlog -f elfs/prs_log.elf | \
grep -E --line-buffered "RSSI|SNR" | sed -n -e 's/^.*RTS\/Grant //p' | tee myfile.txt
```